# How can I get my out of the box search to return result.only for the last 3 years

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search, content-search-web-part

How can I get my out of the box search to return result.only for the last 3 years

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Search Results web part and hard code a date, such as 3/29/2015. But, I don't know of a way to use a calculated date.

The Enterprise Search Center search results pages are web part pages. (The local/site search results page, osssearchresults.aspx, is only editable on the web server.) Go to your search center, do an "Everything" search and then edit the page. Edit the Search Results web part and in the Properties panel click Edit Query.

In the "Query text" box enter something like:

```
write>"3/18/15" AND {searchboxquery}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the search box:

```
write>3/27/15
```

You can create searches on date ranges using “..”.

```
Example: write=2/1/2015..2/8/2015
```

You can also use the names of some date ranges.

```
Example: write="this week"
```

The supported ranges are:

- today
- yesterday
- this week
- this month
- last month
- this year
- last year

Comment: Hi Mike, Can you please elaborate more. What i want is to default my search to show only results for the last 3 years

Comment: In the search box type: write>3/27/15

Comment: Are you asking how to do the search, or how to modify the search results page to only show the last three years?

Comment: Sorry Mike . how t modify the search results page to only show the last 3 years. Thanks

Comment: If I were you I'd add the modifier to the Result Source.

Comment: Thanks Matthew i was thinking of that too but how would you implement it? Any resources you can forward would be appreciated